# Code works in sim, but only sometimes on device

Tags: iphone, imageview

The code to set image to imageView is:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:_url];

    if (cachedImage)
    {
        _imageView.image = cachedImage;
        [spinner stopAnimating];
    }
    else
    {
        [spinner startAnimating]; 
        [manager downloadWithURL:_url delegate:self];
    }

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}


- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager 
     didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)_image 
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    _imageView.image = _image;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

I use [SDWebImage](http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

this works every time in simulator, but when I run the app in the device (Ipod touch) 
80 % of the images is just black, but if I go to another view and back the images are set (from cache).

I have try to set delay on _imageView = _image, but change.

Comment: Are you sure that you are doing this method in the main thread?

Comment: Could we see a bit more code? In particular I'm curious about your management of the image objects.

Comment: I updated the post with more info.

Comment: Please add your answer as a real answer below. Then mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Now I have try the code on a Iphone 3gs and it works perfect, can understand why it wont work on ipod touch.
>
> When i Compiled and Run as "Release" it works on ipod, but not in as debugger. Wierd..